# Disposing a frame in JAVA swing automatically after certain condition fulfills

Tags: java, swing, timer, timertask

I am new to Java, newer to swing. In a project I am trying to dispose a frame when a task is completed. I have a static boolean variable **JobDone** initially set to false in the class (**FinalOutput**) where the main task is performed and after the task gets completed it is set to true. I searched about checking something periodically in java and I found it can be achieved through Timer. Now based on this variable I'm trying to dispose the frame using a Timer.

Below is what I tried:
This code in main function of the frame (**ProgressBarForm**) to be disposed.

```
                ProgressBarForm obj = new ProgressBarForm(); 
                Timer t = new Timer();

                t.scheduleAtFixedRate(new TimerTask(){
                @Override
                public void run(){ 
                    if(FinalOutput.isJobDone())
                        obj.dispose();
                }}, 100, 100);
```

But the frame is not getting disposed after the job gets completed. Kindly help me through this.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: did you debug the return value of `FinalOutput.isJobDone()`?

Comment: No. But the the variable is set to true just after the statement where final output gets produced. I am getting the output file as expected.

Comment: 1) For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/). 2) See also [The Use of Multiple JFrames, Good/Bad Practice?](http://stackoverflow.com/q/9554636/418556)

Comment: I assume this is because you shouldnt call `dispose()` from some random other thread. Just follow the guidance given in the duplicated question. In case that does **not** solve  your problem, feel free to A) update your question indicating that you tried that B) ping me, then I will gladly reopen this question.

Comment: Don't use a `java.util.Timer` in a Swing application but rather a `javax.swing.Timer` or [Swing Timer](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) instead.